# Parametrised formatting of linked locale messages in Vue's i18n

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, internationalization, vue-i18n

I want to link locale messages in vue-i18n with a parameter.
For example when I have a localisation file like that:

```json
{
  "next": "Next step {step+1}: @:steps[{step}]",
  "steps": [
    "Welcome",  // 0 
    "Briefing", // 1
    "Finish"    // 2
  ]
}
```

I would like to use it like this:

```js
$t('next', { step: '1' }) 

// which should result in: "Next step 2: Briefing"
// but instead it leads to: "Next step : Welcome, Briefing, Finish[1]"
```

Is it somehow possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use enums in the i18n file. Here is quick example you can try. I am using it for a project of mine and it works properly:

i18n file:

```
steps: {
    1: "Welcome",
    2: "Briefing",
    3: "Finish",
},
```

Later you can access the enums in your component as:

```
{{ $t(`steps.${step}`) }}
```

Where `step` is your number you want to read from the `steps` i18n file.

Comment: I see, you use template strings to first replace the step variable in order to pass the correct string to i18n? Neat! But this is just a workaround as this code only works in the JS environment and not directly in the localisation files.

Comment: @winklerrr..i have my `steps` array in the localisation file. Maybe i did not understand the question. Sorry my bad!

Comment: No problem, your solution already got me further! Thank you!

Comment: @winklerrr How did you fix this? I'm looking for the same answer...